# Change Shape of List of list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas

I have a data frame  which i converted into a list of list of strings in python like below.

`df=['812957', 'P05', 'P06'], ['812958', 'P05', 'P09', 'P10'], ['812959', 'P07', 'P09'].....`

Now i want it to give me an output like this with columns

`transaction_id            product_id`

`812957                   [P05,P06] 
812958                   [P05, P09, P10]
812959                   [P01, P03]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame([(i[0],i[1:]) for i in df], columns =['transaction_id','product_id'])

     transaction_id       product_id
0         812957       [P05, P06]
1         812958  [P05, P09, P10]
2         812959       [P07, P09]
```